# Examples of an integral extension that $ht P \lt ht P\cap A$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

All rings are commutative Noetherian with 1.
Matsumura's Exercise 9.8. Let $A$ be a ring and $A\subset B$ an integral extension. If $P$ is a prime ideal of $B $ with $p = P\cap A$ then $ht P \leq ht p$.
I have examples that equality occurs; i.e. $ht P = ht p$. But I cannot  see examples that $ht P \lt ht p$. Can you give such examples, please?
Thank you.

Comment: i'd appreciate if one ask this in other sites and then give reference...

Comment: I asked the question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429512/examples-of-integral-ring-extensions-that-operatornamehtp-lt-operatorname

Comment: the question has now an answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429512/examples-of-integral-ring-extensions-that-operatornamehtp-lt-operatorname